# Meteor Deps.autorun doesn't get triggerd - what's its use compared to observe()?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a test collection ("initData") which already contains some documents and the following code on a Meteor client:

```
Meteor.subscribe("initData");

Meteor.startup(function () {
    console.log(InitData.findOne("randIdTest").key);
    Deps.autorun(function() {
        var allInitData = InitData.find();
        allInitData.forEach(function(entry) {
            console.log("Deps foreach: " + entry._id);
        });
        var randomObject = InitData.findOne("randIdTest");
        console.log("Deps call " + randomObject.key);
    });
});

var InitDataObserver = InitData.find().observe({
    added: initDataChange,
    changed: initDataChange,
    removed: initDataChange
});

function initDataChange () {
    var allInitData = InitData.find();
    allInitData.forEach(function(entry) {
        console.log("Observer foreach: " + entry._id);
    });
    var randomObject = InitData.findOne("randIdTest");
    console.log("Observer call " + randomObject.key);
}
```

My initial goal was to find the best way to use data from a collection as soon as it is loaded in the client, as this is not the case when Meteor.startup is triggered. (In the Code above on line 4 I get an error as InitData.findOne("randIdTest") is undefined at that moment.)

I tried to accomplish this with Deps.autorun() and observe() as you can see above. observe() works as you would expect. However Deps.autorun() doesn't get triggered at all (no matter if I delete, modify or add documents - and I've also tried to put it outside the Meteor.startup(fucntion(){})).

Am I understanding Deps.autorun() wrong or have I implemented it wrong? In which case should I use Deps.autorun() and when observe()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, from the docs:

> If the initial run of an autorun throws an exception, the computation is automatically stopped and won't be rerun.

So if your `Meteor.startup` block is executing before your subscription to `InitData` is ready and `randomObject` is undefined, as appears to be the case given that an error is thrown, your `Deps.autorun` won't run again regardless of what you do.

There are methods in the [iron-router](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router) package to deal with this situation very easily, and I would recommend you explore them.  In the above example it's obviously quite straightforward to avoid the error being thrown on the first run by just checking whether `randomObject` is defined, which should get the `Deps.autorun` to work as expected.  Either this or the `observe` block would seem to do the trick for the use case you describe as both will be triggered when the minimongo DB is populated on the client, but an iron-router solution may be cleaner.

Comment: Thanks for all that input. It indeed was due to the undefined randomObject but it looks like Deps.autorun also won't run when there is an error before it is called. So I also had to check for InitData.findOne("randIdTest").key on line 4 and for randomObject on line 11. Now Deps.autorun gets triggered.

I'll now check iron-router and then stick with observe() (as it looks like it is a little faster than Deps.autorun) or use iron-router.